# Is it okay to comment with "idownvotedbecau.se" ?

Tags: discussion, downvote-reason, rude-or-abusive

I've seen a few downvoted questions on StackOverflow, on which the downvoter commented with a link from [idownvotedbecau.se](http://idownvotedbecau.se/) and nothing else.

Is it okay to act this way ? Is it considered rude ?

Comment: Don't sweat it. "Downvote without a comment" is considered rude by some. "Downvote *with* a comment" is considered rude. Any "downvote" **at all** is considered rude; and, finally, any plain old "comment" is considered rude by some as well.